# How to remove configure volumes in docker images

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I use `docker run -it -v /xx1 -v /xx2 [image] /bin/bash` to create a container.

Then commit to image and push to docker hub.

use `docker inspect [image]`

The `Volumes` detail is

```
"Volumes": {
            "/xx1": {},
            "/xx2": {}
        },
```

Now I want to remove volume `/xx1` in this image.

What should I do?

Comment: I had the same question here, with lots of trial/error and explanations:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47043466/docker-compose-reusing-volumes I guess it can't be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with the Docker tools right now. You can't remove a volume from a running container, or if you were to use your image as the base in a new Dockerfile you can't remove the inherited volumes.

Possibly you could use Jérôme Petazzoni's `nsenter` tool to manually remove the mount inside the container and then commit. You can use that approach to [attach a volume to a running container](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/01/13/docker-mount-dynamic-volumes/), but there's some fairly low-level hacking needed to do it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround in that you can `docker save image1 -o archive.tar`, editing the metadata json file, and `docker import -i archive.tar`. That way the history and all the other metadata is preserved.

To help with save/unpack/edit/load I have created a little script, have a look at [docker-copyedit](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-copyedit). Specifically for your question you would execute

```
./docker-copyedit.py from [image] into [image2] remove volume /xx1
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to remove volumes is to export and then import the container image:

- `docker run --name my-container -it [image] /bin/bash`
- `docker export my-container > tarball`
- `docker import tarball`

Comment: too bad export/import doesn't just magically work 99% of the time. It's equivalent to writing a Dockerfile from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question in 2023, and since [release 1.10.1](https://buildah.io/releases/2019/08/16/Buildah-version-v1.10.1.html#changes-for-v1100) you can now use Buildah for this specific task.

For instance, to remove volume `/test_volume` from image `test-image:latest` and save the resulting image in `updated-test-image:latest` :

```
img=$(buildah from test-image:latest)
buildah config --volume /test_volume- $img
buildah commit $img updated-test-image:latest
```

(Pay extra attention to the `-` after `/test_volume`)