# Undo Dockerfile VOLUME directive from a base image

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have an image derived from the Postgres official image, whose [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/11/alpine/Dockerfile) includes the following:

```
VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

I'd like to create my own image based on this official image, but I don't want it to reference any volume.  I'd like the Postgres data to be inside my image.

Any ideas please?

Comment: VOLUME of the base image can't be overridden. We can make Postgres save its data to another position in the container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't undo the `VOLUME` directive.

See this open issue on github: [Reset properties inherited from parent image #3465](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3465)

There are some solutions, based on answers of theses questions:

- ["Remove" a VOLUME in a Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020785/remove-a-volume-in-a-dockerfile)
- [How to remove a volume in a Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49984318/how-to-remove-a-volume-in-a-dockerfile/50051739#50051739)
- [How to remove configure volumes in docker images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39588984/how-to-remove-configure-volumes-in-docker-images)

---

You can copy the base image and remove the `VOLUME` manually.

---

A workaround, see [docker-copyedit](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-copyedit). The script will `docker save` and image into an archive to modify its metadata and `docker load` it back into an image.

---

If you don't care about the volume and just want to put the data in the image, you'll have to use another location for the data and you can use use the environment variable `PGDATA` to define the new location.

Comment: With `PGDATA` I've used another folder location.